# Node MSSQL incorrect syntax near '@input_parameter'

Tags: sql-server, node.js, npm, body-parser

I've been stuck with this error for about a day now

I'm using node.js with html form where the input type=checkbox and i want mssql to use the data posted form the form to query

Let's say with

```
postData = [ '1','2','3','4','5' ]
```

The JS code:

```
var cfg = {
user: 'user',
password: '1234',
server: 'COMPUTERNAME\\SQLEXPRESS',
port: '1433',
database: 'test',
pool: {
    max: 20,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
 }
};

app.post('/select', urlencodedParser, function (req, res){

var in_dt = String();

for (var i = 0; i < req.body.postData.length; i++) {
 if (i==0) {
  in_dt += ("('" + req.body.postData[i] + "'")
 }else if (i==((req.body.postData.length)-1)) {
  in_dt += (", '" + req.body.postData[i] + "')")
 }else {
  in_dt += (", '" + req.body.postData[i] + "'")
 }
};


sql.connect(cfg).then(pool => {
  return pool.request()
  .input('input_parameter', sql.NVarChar, in_dt)
  .query('SELECT * FROM [test].[dbo].[Table1] where ID IN @input_parameter')
}).then(result => {

  res.render('select', { qDt: result.recordset });

  sql.close()
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
})

sql.on('error', err => {
  console.log(err);
})

});
```

It gave me

> Incorrect syntax near '@input_parameter'
>   code: 'EREQUEST'
>   state: 1
>   class: 15

But when i copy the query and the data to run in SSMS it was fine

Can you help me find where the error is and maybe fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think it would work like this , you will have to use sp_executesql .

create the sql as below :

```
let sql = 'SELECT * FROM [test].[dbo].[Table1] where ID IN (@input_parameter)';
```

pass this sql as input parameter.

and in query , put below query ( replace ID,Title with columns you want).

then use  sp_executesql as :

```
create table #tempLookup(ID int , Title nvarchar(MAX));
insert into #tempLookup
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@input_parameter VARCHAR(MAX)', @input_parameter;
select ID,Title from #tempLookup; 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempLookup') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tempLookup
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove ' character
Ex) `in_dt = (1,5,6,4,1)` is OK
    `in_dt = ('1','5','6','4','1')` is not OK

```
var in_dt = String();
for (var i = 0; i < req.body.postData.length; i++) {
 if (i==0) {
  in_dt += ("(" + req.body.postData[i] + "")
 }else if (i==((req.body.postData.length)-1)) {
  in_dt += (", " + req.body.postData[i] + ")")
 }else {
  in_dt += (", " + req.body.postData[i] + "")
 }
};
```

I hope it will help you.